# Polymer - how to query a nested component

Tags: polymer

I have a component nested like the following:

```html
<first-component>
   <second-component>
      <third-component></third-component>
   </second-component>
</first-component>
```

How do I query select third-component?

In Chrome, document.querySelector('third-component') works, but it does not in Firefox.

Thanks guys :)

Comment: So what exactly happens in Firefox?

Comment: In Firefox, when I try to query the nested component, there is a console error that says it is null, I think because it cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a Polymer definition, you can use `this.$$(third-component)`.

Otherwise you should just set an `id` on the tag. Then you can use `document.querySelector('#id')` or `this.$.id` if using Polymer.